# How do I turn off dependency injection for an Angular component?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I've got an Angular component that's used as a superclass (never instantiated on its own).

Because there are a number of other components that extend this one, and each operates on a different type of data, the superclass uses some generic typing.

The superclass also needs to be able to instantiate objects of the provided type. As a result, you can see that the component's constructor takes a parameter that allows me to define a constructor for the generic type.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent<Class1> implements OnInit {

    public object!:Class1;

    constructor(protected type1 : new () => Class1) 
    { 
        this.object = new this.type1();
    }

}
```

Note that when the subclass component calls super(), it *always* passes the actual type (e.g. MyClass), so the component has it available.

Very important: **This all works.** When I run via `ng serve` the generic type gets passed from the subclass component and the whole page functions as it's supposed to.

I'm trying to turn this generic component into a library package that I can use elsewhere, but I'm finding that when I try to build it, I get this error: "error NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter 'type1' of class 'MyComponent'."

Angular's compiler thinks it's supposed to inject something into that constructor parameter, even though I will *never* need it to do so.

How can I turn that off so the compiler will let me build and pass the constructor argument as I already know I can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the `@Component` decorator on the superclass. Use it on the actual components that extend this class.

Or create an [Injection Token](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken) for that `type` function and provide it from the child classes.

```js
// export your typings and use them instead of any
export const TYPE_INJECTION_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<new () => any>(
  'TYPE_INJECTION_TOKEN'
);

// shouldn't this be a directive ? Will you ever call it explicitly?
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html'
})
export class MyComponent {
  public object;

  constructor(_injector: Injector) {
    const factory = _injector.get(TYPE_INJECTION_TOKEN);

    this.object = new factory();
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: TYPE_INJECTION_TOKEN,
      useValue: function () {}, // this is the constructor function
    },
  ],
})
export class AppComponent extends MyComponent {
  constructor(_injector: Injector) {
    super(_injector);
  }
}
```

Comment: Components cannot extend classes that don't have a `@Component` decorator, you will get an angular error unless there is 100% zero angular features in the superclass.

Comment: well it seems to be the case since he wants to 'turn off' DI

Comment: `@Input()` and `@Output()` don't require DI, they can no longer be used in the superclass, same with other Angular property decorators.

Comment: ok... then he can make an Injection Token for that `type` function and provide it from the child components.

Comment: You should elaborate upon your answer

Answer (score 0):

I gave the above poster the check because his answer was correct given the context provided in my question. As some of the commenters pointed out, however, it is not a sufficient answer in the case where a component superclass needs Angular features (like @ViewChild). Since I do use Angular features, I found a different solution:

```
constructor(@Inject(null) protected type1 : new () => Class1) 
{ 
    this.object = new this.type1();
}
```

Apparently `@Inject(null)` is sufficient to tell Angular that it's not supposed to be injecting anything, and the compiler no longer complains.